# How to make event click event fire only once when element is clicked multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link that the user clicks on to delete a record (`class="delMail"`). When they click this link, a new div shows up with 2 more links [Y and N]. clicking on Y will delete their email, clicking on N will cancel the request.

The problem is that if the user clicks 10 times on the delMail link prior to clicking on either Y/N, the code will try to delete the email 10 times also?

I've updated my code to my working version, here it is:

```
$(function(){ //delete Message
    $("a.delMail").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //get divs to show and hide
        var $confirmDelDiv = $(this).parents("tr").next().find(".confirmDelete");
        var $replyDiv = $(this).parents("tr").next().next().find(".replyDiv");

            $replyDiv.fadeOut(); //hide reply div
            $confirmDelDiv.fadeIn("slow"); //show confirm message

            //get id
            var $id = $(this).attr("href"); //get id value of email
            var dataString = "id="+$id;

            $("a.delLinkYes").click(function(y){//if user confirms delete, send id to php page
                y.preventDefault(); $(this).unbind("click");
                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url:  "process.php",
                            action: "deleteEmail",
                            data:  dataString,
                            dataType: "JSON",
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(data){
                                if(data == "true"){//if email was successfully deleted
                                    $confirmDelDiv.delay(60).append("Email deleted!");
                                    $confirmDelDiv.fadeOut("slow");
                                }else{$confirmDelDiv.delay(60).append("Error deleting this email. Please try again!"); return false;}
                            }
                    });
                    return false;
                });

            $("a.delLinkNo").click(function(n){//if user cancels request, stop.
                $(this).unbind("click");alert("cancel"); return false; 
                //$confirmDelDiv.fadeOut("slow"); return false;
            });
    });
});
```

Is this ok? I mean efficiency wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how jQuery functions. You should unbind and rebind the click event handler to stop users from spamming the results. Here is the basic structure:

```
$(function() {
  var delHandler=function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Ignore additional clicks until otherwise stated
    $('a.delMail').unbind('click');

    //Do your stuff
    $.ajax({
      //...
      success:function(data) {
        //...
        //Start listening to user clicks again
        $('a.delMail').bind(delHandler);
      }
    });

    $("a.delLinkNo").click(function(n){
      alert("cancel");
      //Start listening to user clicks again
      $('a.delMail').bind(delHandler);                
      return false;
    });
  }
});
```

I hope the code example makes sense to you. I omitted several parts to try to make it more clear of what I added. Basically, you stop jQuery from caring if the user clicks the button up until it is done processing the second Y/N box.

Comment: Kranu, Please take a look at my revised working code and tell me if my version would have any negative effects opposed to your version??

Comment: Umm, I think you have your code on backwards. You're supposed to bind the delete button back after they click on the Yes/No button. You're supposed to unbind the delete button as soon as they click it. Right now, from your code, you're unbinding the yes/no buttons after they are clicked. You can try it, but I don't think that it will solve your problem. Another way to think of it is setting an on/off switch. As soon as the user clicks delete, the button is turned "off". Then, when they confirm/decline it, the button is turned back "on".

Comment: Implementing my version works : ) The only thing is that the user can still spam the heck out of the delMail link. No action is taken of course, until they hit one of the other links (Y/N), but will this spamming of a link increase server load even though nothing happens until they click on one of the other links?

Comment: Nope it will not increase server load. JQuery is client-side, so in the worst case, they might end up breaking their mouse from clicking too hard, but that's it ;P Maybe I misinterpreted your code or something. Sorry for telling you that it wouldn't work when it does!

Comment: haha, well they can break their mice if they want! The code works and I am moving on. Thanks a bunch all! I am learning a lot. I ve been coding mostly in PHP in the past, so all the input given is surely being absorbed by this noob.

Comment: Oh by the way, do I need to worry about unsetting variables at end of functions,etc in jquery? Will this make a big difference or does it even matter?

Comment: Glad to have helped. Good choice in languages! PHP and Javascript are two of my favorite languages (but then again, those are the only programming languages that I'm comfortable with). And no, you don't really have to worry about garbage in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I would look into using [`jQuery.fn.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) rather than `jQuery.fn.click()` for this. From the documentation it shows that you can:

> Attach a handler to an
>   event for the elements. The handler is
>   executed **at most once per element**.

So it should be as simple as replacing:

```
$("a.delMail").click(function(e) ...
```

With:

```
$("a.delMail").one('click', function(e) ...
```

Comment: +1 - did not know about `one` - though Johny would need to re-bind with `one` 'no' is chosen.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like there may be a lot of things going on in the code. I may supply an alternate answer ;)

Comment: Ooh I forgot about "one". However, like pygorex1 said, it will still need to be rebound. In the end, your method and my method are about the same in terms of simplicty.

Answer (score 0):

As Kranu noted this is just how click handling works in jQuery - though it's not specific to jQuery, but the JavaScript `onclick` event that fires.

There's several possible workarounds. Use [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) (scroll down to the section "Using the Event Object") to remove the click handler when the delete button is pressed for that element. You will need to re-`bind` the click handler whenever the user selects 'no'.

Another option would be to keep a global lookup object such as `window.pendingDeletes = {}` (keyed by message_id) to track when a delete has been triggered, but not confirmed, and have the `click` handler `return false` whenever an message has a pending yes/no decision about a delete.